# Is there an exhaustive list of plugins for Dovecot?

Tags: plugin, dovecot

**Background**
I am looking for plugins for Dovecot (specifically authentication plugins) because I would like to look at source code for reference as to how to make an authentication plugin for Dovecot.

I have search through the official list on the [Dovecot website](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins) as well as a [Google search](https://www.google.com/?hl=en#hl=en&q=dovecot%20plugin%20list) for a list of plugins available. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything that fits what I am looking for.

**Questions**
Are there more plugins available than in the official list?
Where can I find these plugins?
Are there any authentication plugins available for Dovecot?

I am looking for a response that answers all of the questions above.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Can you use PAM?

Comment: I was actually just looking up information on that and it looks like PAM is the best option.

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pluggable Authentication Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) are probably the way to go.  Dovecot has [its own documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/PAM) on integration with PAM.

The exact list of plugins available depends on your platform -- I use [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/pam-freebsd-modules.html), but you may use [Linux](http://debian.securedservers.com/kernel/pub/linux/libs/pam/modules.html).

I would say that there is probably *not* an exhaustive list of PAM plugins, but each OS or distro will have a list of plugins that it includes or supports.  Others may be portable with a little effort.

Comment: More sensible advice than editing the source directly. Would it be possible to get some information on the settings needed to add the new pam service to the Dovecot authentication list? I already have information as to how to make the binary, so I won't be needing that. http://www.rkeene.org/projects/info/wiki/222 Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dovecot's [QuickConfiguration page](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/QuickConfiguration#Authentication) has some sample PAM configuration for you, and I believe the second link in my answer points to where this is configured within Dovecot. The location of configuration files will depend on your OS or distro.  And you're very welcome! :)

Comment: I'll check out the information on the page and get back to you once it has been confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one can find a list of currently installed plugins like so:

```
ls -1 /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/*plugin.so \
    | perl -pe 's/.*lib.._(.*)_plugin.so/$1/g' \
    | sort

acl
apparmor
charset_alias
fts
fts_squat
imap_acl
imap_old_stats
imap_quota
imap_zlib
last_login
lazy_expunge
listescape
mail_crypt
mail_crypt_acl
mail_log
mail_lua
mailbox_alias
notify
notify_status
old_stats
pop3_migration
push_notification
push_notification_lua
quota
quota_clone
replication
trash
virtual
welcome
zlib
```